# Black shadowy mesh in Edit Mode

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, faces

I am in Edit Mode trying to visualize the bottom part of my model.
But the bottom meshes are black and so are the parts on the other side.

[image]

I looked at [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker) and [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29207/why-are-there-dark-shadows-on-model-in-edit-view) but I don't think they are related to my problem.

I'm in Edit Mode with Material shading turned on (to be able to see the reference images imported as planes), and would like to see the faces and vertices on the sides that are currently dark.

Comment: My first guess is that this is a face-normals issue; if this is the case, the first answer in the first question you looked at should resolve it. Select the whole mesh, and under the shading tab in the tool shelf (on the left) try recalculate normals.

Comment: You've set viewport shading to material  (the drop down right to edit mode) it seems that there is no light in this direction either add another light source or change to a different mode.

Comment: Recalculating normals didn't change the black parts of the mesh, but stacker's answer was the right one: in material view, the shadows appear closer to final render and adding a light solved it. @stacker please make your comment an answer to be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the viewport shading to material (the drop down right to edit mode) it seems that there is no light in this direction either add another light source or change to a different mode.

[image]